Why can't a cafeteria serve chilled apples?
I like a cold apple. My cafeteria sells room temperature apples. My cafeteria has refrigerators that hold many cold products. Those refrigerators have lots of unused room. Being the trouble maker that I am I placed an apple in the fridge. Figured I'd come back for it later.
Being the honest guy that I am I confessed to this crime at check out. When I asked if this would be a problem I was shocked at how vehemently this idea was condemned.
I went back and removed the offending apple. As I paid for it I asked, "Is there any reason I shouldn't put this in my own fridge?" "Oh that's fine". They explained this is only an issue with their fridges which have to conform to health codes.
I know bureaucracy can get out of hand. Is their any good explanation for this rule? Or is bureaucracy at it again?

I’m voting to close this question because it is out of the scope as defined in [help]. Please do not post rants as questions, and note that we cannot guess at the motivations behind organisations' decisions.

@rumtscho Can you at least tell me if the apple in my fridge is safe to eat? I didn't ask for the history that created this rule. I asked for an explanation from people that likely know more about apples than I do. Is this a valid concern?

The fridge you put it in might have been for ‘low risk’ items.  Stuff like canned and bottled drinks which wouldn’t transfer anything that might harbor bacterial growth unless they burst, and can’t easily spoil.  Even in other fridges they probably have all food in containers, not just sitting bare on the fridge shelves.  Chilling an apple itself is not directly dangerous, but can introduce other risk

@Joe I hadn't thought of that! The cafeteria fridge did contain exactly such items. The apple in question was wrapped in cellophane (cling wrap). Not sure if that matters. Pity you can't post that as an answer.

This question discussed on meta

This obviously depends on local laws, but at least where I am in the EU, food establishments have to strictly track and separate potential allergens. An apple is likely not that dangerous (nuts would certainly be), but putting it somewhere that's supposed to be allergen-free is still likely a bad idea for food safety reasons. Nobody will probably die because of your apple, but the operator could get fined if somebody noticed and complained that their allergen regime was a mess.
